# Is water equivalent of a calorimeter valid at temperatures below 273 K?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, phase-transition

Recently I came across a question which stated- **A calorimeter of water equivalent 40 g contains 80 g of ice at 253K.** What does this statement mean? Does it mean that the calorimeter contains 40 g water and 80 g ice at a temperature 253 K? If the calorimeter contains ice at 253 K , is the temperature of the calorimeter 253 K too? What does the term *water equivalent* mean **in this case** when initial temperature of the calorimeter is less than 273 K?

Comment: The specific heat of ice is roughly half of the specific heat of water, so to get a heat capacity equivalent to 40 g of water, you'd need roughly 80 g of ice. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: But the calorimeter could have contained any amount of ice(the data given here matches splendidly with your analogy!).I don't really find any reason why the ice content can't be something other than 80g (maybe I'm missing something!). But how can one define water equivalent for a calorimeter which is at a temperature less than 273 K?

Comment: I think you can define a 40 g water equivalent calorimeter that's made of _any_ material, as long as it has the same heat capacity as 40 g of water. For example, a 40 g water equivalent calorimeter can be made of 186 g of aluminum.

Comment: @probably_someone You should put your comments together as an answer.

Comment: @BobD The reason they're not is because I'm not actually sure if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: But when we determine the water equivalent of a calorimeter via an experiment, we usually take cold water in the calorimeter and a certain amount of hot water is poured into it. In this case, the temperature of the calorimeter cannot be less than 273 K. So can you please explain why we could apply the same definition of water equivalent for a calorimeter well below 273 K?